# While loop in mysqli_fetch_assoc repeating output

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

**This is my code**

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM transaction";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sqli);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2) ) {
   echo "Test : " . $row['id'];

}
```

**OUTPUT: Test : 192Test : 193Test : 194Test : 195Test : 196Test : 197**

I only want to display the last ID which is 197. How can I do that?

Comment: Yea, thats what your code is supposed to do. What do you mean by ___repeated___

Comment: I suppose you do realise that the numbers are all different right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I only want to display the last ID which is 197. How can I do that

Comment: quite a few ways to do this and depends why you only want the last one.

Answer (score 1):

To display only one specific row, amend the SQL to get just that row

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE id = 197";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sqli);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
echo "Test : " . $row['id'];
```

Or as @Funky says, if you just want the last row from the table whatever `row.id` that may be

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM transaction 
        ORDER BY id DESC
        LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sqli);

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
echo "Test : " . $row['id'];
```

Comment: sure, either that or LIMIT with an OFFSET

Comment: Not specific 197 but the last unique ID everytime the user trigger the button. For now my unique ID is 250. (Sorry for bad english)

Comment: `last_insert_id()` also comes to mind, but that's just *my 2 cents*.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Not doing an INSERT so that would not help here

Comment: @RiggsFolly true; but we don't quite know why they want to choose only the last entry.

Comment: may I have 1 more question? everytime I refresh the page the stock number keep decreasing. I only want to decrease it everytime the users hit the button

Comment: @RiggsFolly 1 more question here :D

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner 1 more question here :D

Comment: @RonnelDelaPeña what other question? and why is this question still considered as "open/unsolved"? this answer should be marked as solved.